# How to remove attribute from Product Collection

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes, product-collection

I have created an observer that manipulates the advanced search result of Magento.
For this, I've used the `controller_action_layout_render_before_catalogsearch_advanced_result` observer.

I'm using an "dummy" attribute called "brand". This attribute doesn't accually contain something, but is just there so that the user can input a value in the normal magento forms.

Now my problem is that I can not seem to remove this dummy attribute. I've tried `removeAttributeFromFilter()` (and `removeFieldFromFilter()`) but it does not seem to disappear.

I cannot just reset the WHERE statement, because all other attributes do need to function like normal.

The observer:

```
class Jeroen_SearchFilter_Model_Observers_Searchresults
{
      function manipulateSQL( $event ){
         if(!Mage::app()->getRequest()->getOriginalPathInfo() == "/catalogsearch/advanced/result/";){ 
            //double check if this we're really using advanced search
            return;
         }

         $block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('search_result_list');

         if($block){
             $collection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
             $searchFilterTable = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('searchFilter/searchtable');
             $collection->getSelect()->join(array("searchfilter" => $searchFilterTable), "e.entity_id = searchfilter.product_id" );
             $collection->getSelect()->where("searchfilter.brandAttributeId = 'mybrand'");
             $collection->removeAttributeFromFilter("brand");
             $block->setLoadedProductCollection($collection);
         }
      }

}
```

Does anyone know how to remove the brand attribute from the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to construct a new query. Once you hit the DB with a query with conditions, you can't just remove a condition and have new data, you have to construct a new query.

Afaik standard Magento does not have any methods to explicitely remove filters (besides `clear()`, which resets all filters and unloads the collection).

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391320/how-to-remove-attributes-which-are-added-through-addattributetofilter-from/9391704#9391704) for more information

Comment: This is what I have now, plus array and range support (from, to price for example).

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge the only way is to edit the where part and remove the part where the condition is set on the attribute you want to remove:

```
$where = $collection->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE);
foreach ($where as $key => $condition)
{
    // You may have to adapt this condition depending on the situation
    if (strpos("brand",$condition) !== false)
    {
        unset($where[$key]);
    }
}
$collection->getSelect()->setPart(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE, $where);
```